# Using ajax in for each loop to refresh a div content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Jquery/Ajax rookie here

This is how my code should work...

When the submit button is clicked, JavaScript  handles the form and post the values to the same page. The values are used in a SQL query to update a column in the database. The value from the column is echoed out and updated each time the button is clicked (SQL UPDATE QUERY), all this would be done without refreshing the page using ajax (i.e "**ONLY**" the value from the database would be refreshed when the button is clicked and the page **shouldn't scroll back** to the top). The problem is my JavaScript isn't handling the form submission as i expect it to. The div around the value isn't refreshing, i have to redirect to a different page and back to see the changes (SQL query works). How do i solve my problem to achieve this?

**file.php**

```
  <html>
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1
       /jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ajaxform').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
      type: "POST", // POST
      url: "file.php", // the file to call
      success: function(response) { // on success..
      $('#emailform').html("Thank you!"); // update the DIV
        }
          });
       return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
       });
           }); 
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>

  <?php
  ...................
  foreach($stmt as $obj){

      $id = $obj['id'];
      $likes = $obj['like1'];


      echo '<form action="" method="post" id="ajaxform"        
             enctype="multipart/form-data">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="like" value="">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15" 
             value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
             margin-right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';
      echo '</form>’;
      echo '<div id="emailform"></div>';
     }
      ?>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**query.php**

```
  <?php
    if( isset( $_POST['lkcv'] ) && is_array( $_POST['lkcv'] ) )
    {
      $idArray = array();
      foreach( $_POST['lkcv'] as $value )
  {
    $idArray[] = intval( $value );
   }

   $db->query( "UPDATE comment SET like1 = like1 + 1 WHERE id IN (".implode( 
   ',', $idArray ).")" );
      }
         ?>
```

**NOTE:** file.php always has a dynamic url such as "file.php?post=1"

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` I guess, If I understood the question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know php, so apologies if some of this is wrong.

does file.php write out a full html page? If so, it should only be sending out a fragment as ajax deals with partial updates rather than pulling in an entire page.

In your success handler, you are only updating the #emailForm div, when really you also want to be replacing the content on the page with the new version.

2nd, in html, tags with an id are expected to be unique.  You output

```
<div id="emailForm"></div>
```

in a loop, therefore, it isn't unique on the page, so you might not get the right one being updated

There is a parameter for $.ajax called cache, setting that will append a timestamp to your query, ensuring it is unique, no need to manually create a unique url.

```
$.ajax({
     cache: false, 
     ....
```

Lastly, to make sure that you are getting fresh content, check your web server logs to look for a http response, which means that the content hasn't changed, so the webserver sent a cached copy

```
 <html>
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1
       /jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#content').on("submit", "form", function(e) { // catch the form's submit event
          $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
               data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
               type: "POST", // POST
               cache: false,
               url: "file.php?=" + $(e.currentTarget).find("name=lkcv[]").val(), // the file to call
               success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $(e.currentTarget).html(response); // only replace the form that caused the submit
                    $('#emailform').html("Thank you!"); // update the DIV
                }
          });
       return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
       });
           }); 
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>

   <?php
   ...................
   echo '<div id=content>';

   foreach($stmt as $obj){

      $id = $obj['id'];
      $likes = $obj['like1'];

      echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="like" value="">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15" 
             value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
             margin-right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';
      echo '</form>’;
     }
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<div id="emailform"></div>';
      ?>
```

Comment: yes "file.php?id=1" writes out 80% of the content of the page as the value from the id, "1" is used to generate the content from my database, same goes for "2" which will load a different content.

Comment: the major problem now is javascript isn't handing the form submission, i've added  `$('#ajaxform').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();`. but that didnt work

Comment: sorry, just spotted the id in the form.  and html id attribute should have a unique value in the page, otherwise it will be at the browsers whim as to which you get.  So change $("#ajaxform") to just $("form"), I'll update the answer

Comment: thanks for your help, getting closer. problem now is the button loads the whole page again, underneath the original page. i only want the div class "ld" and its content to be reloaded. i've added `success: function(response) { // on success..
      $(".ld").html(response);
      $(".ld").replaceWith($('.ld', $(html)));` which doesnt work. i think the problem is in `url:file.php` as the page i am currently on is `file.php?=6`

Comment: I've added an update to the ajax call, it will now find the lkcv[] field, and append the value of that onto file.php.  And the response handler, will now replace the form that triggered the submit.  your file.php will need to output just the form when it gets called with a param, and all when it gets called without

Comment: using `name=lkcv[]` causes my update query to stop working. please have a look at this modification `$('.ajaxform').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // catch the form's submit event
      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      data: $(this).serialize(), 
      type: "POST", // POST
      url: "info.php",
      cache: false, 
      success: function(html) { // on success..
      var div = $('.ld', $(html)).addClass('ld');
        $('.ld').html(div);
        $('.ld').show();

        }
          });
       return false; 
       });
           });`

Comment: That almost works except the value is hidden when i click the button, but returns if i manually reload the page.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?